# What's the difference between sh script and sh < script

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

What's the difference between

```
sh myscript
```

and

```
sh < myscript
```

I played around and they seem to have the same effect. Are they equivalent?

Comment: They aren't the same. The first will open the file along w/ any cmd line args after it. The 2nd will stream the contents of the file `myscript` into STDIN of sh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not. There are some things that will not work. The one thing that comes to mind is:

```
sh myscript -flag1 -value=3
```

is not possible with `sh < myscript`.

With `sh < myscript`, $0 is set to `sh`, rather than `myscript`, so

```
echo this script is $0
```

won't work

Also, if your script reads input, it will not work - you cannot

```
sh < myscript < myfiletoread
```